# How to stop iterating through a 2D array once matches are found?

Tags: c#, arrays

Im doing image template matching using EMGU and C#. EMGU's method of finding matches was a bit slow, so I tried iterating through the image (2D array) to find matches. It works great and very fast. But for some reason, it finds multiple matches of same template on same location and draws multiple times over it. For example, if in my image there are 4 matches of given template, it will draw 10 rectangle each on each matched area for those 4 matches, so the rectangle thickness increases and the total match count is never correct.

Here is the code :

```
         for (int y = 0; y < Matches.Data.GetLength(0); y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < Matches.Data.GetLength(1); x++)
                {
                    if (Matches.Data[y, x, 0] >= Threshold) //Set at 0.9
                    {
                        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(new Point(x, y), template.Size);
                        CvInvoke.Rectangle(imgres, r, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0), 1, LineType.EightConnected, 0);
                        listBox1.Items.Add(r.Size); // more than 80 rectangles are drawn for 4 matches
                    }                       
                }                    
            }
```

How do I stop the iterations once each matches have been found once?

Answer (score 1):

You could use **break;** but this gets messy fast in nested loops.

Lets go over **for** loops quick,
they are structured like this:

```
for (declaration; condition; execute after) 
{
  // code block
}
```

Since the middle part is a simple condition, you can just add another condition indicating that it is done (or still searching). In this case just a boolean:

```
bool stillSearching = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100 && stillSearching; i++)
    {
        if (i > 50) //You found your match
        {
            stillSearching = false;
        }
    }
```

This will simply count to 51, then the **if** sets the **boolean** to **false**.
It than goes back to the for loop, executes the **i++**.
Then it checks the both conditions:
**i < 100** is still true
**stillSearching** is false

Since there is an **&&** the whole condition is **false** and the loop stops.

Edit:
Since I'm not sure what conditions you need to satisfy, I'll just add an if

```
bool searching = true;

for (int y = 0; y < Matches.Data.GetLength(0) && searching; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matches.Data.GetLength(1) && searching; x++)
            {
                if (Matches.Data[y, x, 0] >= Threshold) 
                {
                    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(new Point(x, y), template.Size);
                    CvInvoke.Rectangle(imgres, r, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0), 1, LineType.EightConnected, 0);
                    listBox1.Items.Add(r.Size); 
                }

                if ( /*your condtion here*/ )
                {
                   searching = false;
                }   
            }                    
        }
```

Comment: Hi Felix, Can you explain a bit more, where should I put this loop and condition?

Comment: @Alisha, I added something to my awnser.
Also as istepaniuk suggested, making this its own Method and using return will not only solve your problem but will also tidy up your code.

Comment: it didnt work.  But I tried enclosing the codes in a while(true) loop, and it works and draws only once, but takes a looong time. Is there any faster alternative?

Answer (score 1):

### Use a `return` statement.

For that to be tidy, keep the loop and action in separate, short methods.

```
for (int y = 0; y < Matches.Data.GetLength(0); y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < Matches.Data.GetLength(1); x++)
    {
        if (Matches.Data[y, x, 0] >= Threshold)
        {
            DoSomethingWithMatch(x, y);

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, for performance reasons, you should not access the C# property inside the loop. Save `Matches.Data` in a variable first and iterate over that.

Comment: Hi, It didnt work. But I tried enclosing the codes in a while(true) loop, and it works and draws only once, but takes a looong time. Is there any faster alternative?

Comment: @Alisha there if you are exiting at the first match, there isn't a much you can do in this sense. However, you can avoid accessing `Matches.Data` inside the loop. I added a paragraph to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `break` to get out of a loop, but it only gets you out of the closest loop you're in. The way around this is to set flag to indicate whether you should break out of the outer loop. Consider the following:

```
     for (int y = 0; y < Matches.Data.GetLength(0); y++)
        {
            bool matchFound = false;
            for (int x = 0; x < Matches.Data.GetLength(1); x++)
            {
                if (Matches.Data[y, x, 0] >= Threshold) //Set at 0.9
                {
                    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(new Point(x, y), template.Size);
                    CvInvoke.Rectangle(imgres, r, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0), 1, LineType.EightConnected, 0);
                    listBox1.Items.Add(r.Size); // more than 80 rectangles are drawn for 4 matches
                    matchFound = true;
                    break;
                }                       
            }
            if(matchFound) 
            {
                break;
            }               
        }
```

Comment: Or you wrap 'for' loop in function and just do `return`

Comment: @Chuck , I tried as you suggested, but it breaks after drawing the first rectangle. Interestingly, when I call the method again to find match, it draws the second rect and so on.

Comment: @Chuck,  It didnt work very well. But I tried enclosing the codes in a while(true) loop, and it works and draws only once, but takes a looong time. Is there any faster alternative?

Comment: @Alisha I think you could consider changing the for loops to while loops, so you can alter the loop variable, and then to skip looking inside of regions you've already identified. You are getting an x/y position and making a Rectangle, so that Rectangle should (I think) indicate a match and further searching inside that Rectangle is (1) a waste of time and (2) likely to generate these redundant results that you're observing, where you just find the same feature multiple times.